# I need help installing "CiscoPacketTracer_821_Ubuntu_64bit.deb" I am on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: dpkg

```
alon@ALON:~/Descargas$ sudo dpkg -i CiscoPacketTracer_821_Ubuntu_64bit.deb
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 172559 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar CiscoPacketTracer_821_Ubuntu_64bit.deb ...
Desempaquetando packettracer (8.2.1) sobre (8.2.1) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: No theme index file.
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de packettracer:
 packettracer depende de libgl1-mesa-glx; sin embargo:
  El paquete `libgl1-mesa-glx' no está instalado.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete packettracer (--install):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Procesando disparadores para shared-mime-info (2.2-1) ...
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 packettracer
```

```
alon@ALON:~/Descargas$ sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete libgl1-mesa-glx no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

E: El paquete «libgl1-mesa-glx» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
```

Comment: Try manually installing `libgl1-mesa-glx` package using `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: The formal method (as adviced by Cisco) is `sudo apt install ./CiscoPacketTracer_821_Ubuntu_64bit.deb`